# Advanced filter in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an advanced filter in excel. The two conditions to be satisfied are in cells g2 and h2. The first condition is show all values `<=0.01` and the second condition is show all values `<20`. I have the following VBA code

```
Sub RefreshAdvancedFilter()
   Range("A6:M5000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("G1:H2"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `Doesn't seem to work` Also if your range is g2 and h2 then why are you using `"G1:H2"`

Comment: g1:h2 because the headers of the columns are specified in G1 and H1 amnd the criteria in G2 and H2. It works when for example I have <x and =y, but when I want <x <y for example, it doesn't

Comment: Strange, i just tested it an it works for me... http://wikisend.com/download/349868/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

If the headers in G1 and H1 are the same and G2 is <=0.01 and H2 is <=20 the only things that will meet BOTH criteria is exactly what you are seeing. Your experience seeing <0.01 and =20 would work however.

I think this may be a case of AND rather than OR being evaluated for.

Try changing your criteria range to G1:G3

Include the header in G1, <=0.01 in G2, and <=20 in G3